# How can I call PHP scripts using JQuery or AJAX without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**UPDATED CODE** I am trying to call a PHP scripts in my main PHP file where everything will be displayed. I just want to display the results from my PHP script with the SQL queries that are being run.

Id also like to include the possibility of showing the results dynamically/by not refreshing the page.

this is what I tried so far, im new to Jquery and AJAX. thanks in advance!

**JQuery/AJAX part:**

```
<div id="map_size" align="center">
<script type="text/javascript">
                    //Display station information in a hidden DIV that is toggled
                    //And call the php script that queries and returns the results LIVE
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".desk_box").click(function() {
                        $id = $(this).attr("data")
                    $("#station_info_"+$id).toggle();
                        
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"display_stationinfo.php",
                        success:function(result){
                    $("#map_size").html(result);
                    }});//end ajax  
                    });//end click
                    });//end ready
    </script>
</div> <!-- end map_size -->
```

**display_station.php (script that I want to call):**

```
<?php
include 'db_conn.php';
//query to show workstation/desks information from DB for the DESKS
$station_sql = "SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord, section_name FROM coordinates";
$station_result = mysqli_query($conn,$station_sql);

//see if query is good
if($station_result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}


//Display workstations information in a hidden DIV that is toggled
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($station_result)){
    //naming values
    $id       = $row['coordinate_id'];
    $x_pos    = $row['x_coord'];
    $y_pos    = $row['y_coord'];
    $sec_name = $row['section_name'];
    //display DIV with the content inside
$html = "<div class='station_info' id='station_info".$id."' style='position:absolute;left:".$x_pos."px;top:".$y_pos."px;'>Hello the id is:".$id."</br>Section:".$sec_name."</br></div>";
}//end while loop for station_result
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' .json_encode($html) . ')';             
mysqli_close($conn); // <-- DO I NEED TO INCLUDE IT HERE OR IN MY db_conn.php SINCE IM INCLUDING IT AT THE TOP?
```

?>

Comment: `post: "GET",` == `type: "GET",`

Comment: what about it? it didnt give me any results

Comment: your php script must echo a result in order to be received by the  done callback. Doesn't one of your alerts go off?

Comment: are you still facing the problem !!! does my answer helps?

Comment: I updated my code as you can see it above. I'm facing problems combining for JQuery toggle function and using AJAX to call my PHP script

Comment: `  echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' .json_encode($html) . ')';    ` here you r getting error ? right?

Comment: yes I am getting the error there.. I moved to another thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365536/how-do-i-call-a-php-script-using-ajax-inside-of-a-jquery-toggle-function?noredirect=1#comment41389806_26365536

Answer (score 2):

You should find out what are the ways in which you can make [jquery ajax calls](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery--net-6289)

Other basic tutorial which will help you in ajax is below

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm

> **Since you have not explained clearly the question i am making genral assumption and going to give you two answer on how you can use ajax for your purpose**

## 1.AJAX LOAD

Lets say your HTML structure is

> **HTML**

```
<div id="map_size" align="center"></div>
```

---

> **MY JS FILE**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery("#map_size").load("myphp.php", {}, function() { });
})
```

---

> **PHP**

```
echo "<p>THIS IS TEST FOR DEMO AJAX LOAD</p>"
```

you can do much more if you are retrieving from db.

> **myphp.php**

```
//get number of rows for X,Y coords in the table
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($coord_result)){    
//naming X,Y values
$x_pos = $row['x_coord'];
$y_pos = $row['y_coord'];


//draw a box with a DIV at its X,Y coord     
echo "<div id='desk_box' style='style:absolute;
                                    left: " . $x_pos. " px;
                                    top:  " . $y_pos. " px;'>box number</div>";
    }
```

you can also do same thing on button click and load everything dynamically without refreshing page

## 2.Jquery Ajax [GET, POST] : [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

This also can be used

> **HTML**

```
<div id="map_size" align="center"></div>
```

---

> **MY JS FILE**
>
> //http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({url:"myphp.php",success:function(result){
       $("#map_size").html(result);
   }});
})
```

---

> **myphp.php**

```
//get number of rows for X,Y coords in the table
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($coord_result)){    
//naming X,Y values
$x_pos = $row['x_coord'];
$y_pos = $row['y_coord'];


//draw a box with a DIV at its X,Y coord     
$html = "<div id='desk_box' style='style:absolute;
                                    left: " . $x_pos. " px;
                                    top:  " . $y_pos. " px;'>box number</div>";
    } 
 //create a JSON 
  echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($html ) . ')';
```

Comment: did this solve your problem ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I will try this and let you know ASAP. thanks

Comment: No problem , take your time :)

Comment: hey, I updated my code as you see above. When I click on the ".desk_box" DIV it shows me this error : Notice: Undefined index: callback in C:\webroot\display_station.php on line 23 ("  that is where im doing json_encode .. basically I want to combine the click/toggle function with the AJAX call for the PHP script. @hitesh

Comment: heres the link to the new opened post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363123/how-can-i-call-a-php-script-using-jquery-toggle-and-ajax/26364441?noredirect=1#comment41387568_26364441