# How can I call a PHP script using JQuery toggle and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a PHP script in my main PHP file . I want to display the results from my PHP script with the SQL queries that are being run.

I'd also like to include the possibility of showing the results dynamically/by not refreshing the page.

this is what I tried so far, im new to Jquery and AJAX. thanks in advance!

**working fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/52n861ee/ 
thats what I want to do but when I click on it will tell me error: line 23 (" where I am using json_encode

**JQuery/AJAX part:**

```
<div id="map_size" align="center">
<script type="text/javascript">
                    //Display station information in a hidden DIV that is toggled
                    //And call the php script that queries and returns the results LIVE
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".desk_box").click(function() {
                        $id = $(this).attr("data")
                    $("#station_info_"+$id).toggle();

                    $.ajax({
                        url:"display_stationinfo.php",
                        type: "GET",
                        success:function(result){
                    $("#station_info_"+$id).html(result);
                    }});//end ajax  
                    });//end click
                    });//end ready
    </script>
</div> <!-- end map_size -->
```

**display_station.php (script that I want to call):**

```
<?php
include 'db_conn.php';
//query to show workstation/desks information from DB for the DESKS
$station_sql = "SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord, section_name FROM coordinates";
$station_result = mysqli_query($conn,$station_sql);

//see if query is good
if($station_result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}


//Display workstations information in a hidden DIV that is toggled
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($station_result)){
    //naming values
    $id       = $row['coordinate_id'];
    $x_pos    = $row['x_coord'];
    $y_pos    = $row['y_coord'];
    $sec_name = $row['section_name'];
    //display DIV with the content inside
$html = "<div class='station_info' id='station_info".$id."' style='position:absolute;left:".$x_pos."px;top:".$y_pos."px;'>Hello the id is:".$id."</br>Section:".$sec_name."</br></div>";
}//end while loop for station_result
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' .json_encode($html) . ')';             
mysqli_close($conn); // <-- DO I NEED TO INCLUDE IT HERE OR IN MY db_conn.php SINCE IM INCLUDING IT AT THE TOP?
```

?>

Comment: Once (if) you get a response from the ajax call, it will replace the `<script> ... </script>` block.

Comment: what do you mean it will replace the script block?

Comment: Set your ajax type post or get

Comment: When you run `$("#map_size").html(result);`, `result` becomes the new contents of `#map_size` .... that's not a good place to put your script. The best place is an external file. Let us know if we should clarify further.

Comment: @user3558931  I updated my code and included a JSfiddle of what I want it to look like.. that works if I include both of my PHP scripts in my main.. but since I'm trying to call it with AJAX it won't do anything. I see the mistake I did with $("#map_size").html(result); .. so since i'm trying to target #station_info_ shouldn't I replace it for that with the ID?

Comment: Take a look at my analysis in the answer below. ... And, yes, the incoming content should go to the same element you're toggling.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. In your PHP script you're treating a html string as though it was an object or array --- **you cannot output a string literal as JSON**
2. In your JS script you're treating the 'JSON' [object] as though it was a string literal or a html object --- **you cannot output JSON that way, you need to use DOT notation to access it's data**.
3. Even though your PHP script seems to be sending `JSONP` you have not specified a `jsonp` `dataType` in your `ajax` call.

Assuming all your PHP scripts are on the same domain, change `echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' .json_encode($html) . ')';` to:

```
echo $html;
```

So that your PHP output is consistent with what your JS expects.

Comment: alright, so I changed what you told me. Still no DIV is being toggled when I click? thansk for explaining my problems in my code!

Comment: Is there anyway to see your live set up?

Comment: What do you see when you load `display_stationinfo.php` in your browser ... via url such as `http://yourserver.com/base_folder/display_stationinfo.php`?

Comment: If I include the echo inside the while loop :I see all the DIVs on their appropiate coordinates like so: http://jsfiddle.net/2t4yrL0m/   if I put the echo outside my while loop I will only see the last row ID DIV on screen.

Comment: Your `PHP` script needs some work but that may not solve the issue. ***I can't c I can't tell*** Initialize `$html='';` before the while loop, then in the loop concatenate the strings if you intention is to see all the `divs`: `$html .= ......`